# Beamer with ignorenonframetext ignores \maketitle command too. Why?

Tags: beamer

I am trying to follow workflow from BEAMER manual (ref. 21.2.2). I want to use the same TeX code to produce both presentation and article. So, I have created three files as advised: main.tex, main.beamer.tex, main.article.tex.
I am able to compile article but I fail to do a correct presentation.

LaTeX code `\maketitle` just simply doesn't work in main.beamer.tex.
Have a look at the code:
**main.tex**

```
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage{graphics}

\usetheme{Warsaw}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}

\begin{document}

\title[Свободные ГИС]{Свободные ГИС}
\subtitle{опыт применения}
\author[Владимир Наумов]{Владимир Наумов}
\institute{Консалтинговый центр}
\date{\today}

% [1] Первый титульный слайд
\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}

%\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<+->}

% [2] Слайд с содержанием доклада (актуально если доклад больше 10-15 минут)
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{О чём этот доклад}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}
\end{document}
Оценка воздействия на окружающую среду (ОВОС) - выявление, анализ и учет прямых, косвенных и иных последствий воздействия на окружающую среду планируемой хозяйственной и иной деятельности в целях принятия решения о возможности или невозможности ее осуществления.
```

**main.beamer.tex**

```
%\documentclass{beamer}
\documentclass[ignorenonframetext]{beamer}
%\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\input{main.tex}
```

When I run `pdflatex` with edited main.beamer.tex (documentclass without ignorenonframetext option) it works well.

The option `ignorenonframetext` should ignore only text outside frames, as far as I know. But in my case it also ignores the text intended for the title frame.

What is the reason that beamer (with `ignorenonframetext` option) suppresses the text usually made with `\maketitle`
 command?

Comment: The reason is that with the option, `beamer` ignores everything after `\begin{document}` which is not inside a `frame`. Put `\begin{document}` after the declarations of `\title`, `\author` and so on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is that with the option, `beamer` ignores everything after `\begin{document}` that is not inside a `frame`.

Put `\begin{document}` after the declarations of `\title`, `\author` and so on; this works also in all standard classes.

```
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage{graphics}

\usetheme{Warsaw}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}

\title[Свободные ГИС]{Свободные ГИС}
\subtitle{опыт применения}
\author[Владимир Наумов]{Владимир Наумов}
\institute{Консалтинговый центр}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
```